# MVC4 view is not detecting JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a @Html.DropDownList which calls a jquery function. But it failed to call the function.
I have tried-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.test').change(function () {
        alert("1");            
    });
});

@Html.DropDownList("PropertyContent", ViewBag.PropertyList as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class="test"})
```

and

```
function test() {
        alert("1");
    }

@Html.DropDownList("PropertyContent", ViewBag.PropertyList as List<SelectListItem>, new { onchange="test();"})


@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") is also included in the view
```

Whats wrong here?

Comment: What's the error? Do you see any error in console? Are you include `jQuery` in your page?

Comment: Also you must write `$('.test')` instead of `$('test')`. Because you want to access elements with `test` class.

Comment: @Mojtaba- I have updated my question. Actually I tried with $('.test'). I am not getting any error. Its not invoking the function!

Comment: Confirm that jQuery actually shows up in view source - if you have a folder physically named the same as your bundle path, bundling won't work.

Comment: Please read about [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your jQuery selector is wrong, use the id-selector instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#PropertyContent').change(function () {
        alert("1");            
    });
});
```

A few more possible errors:

- jQuery is not referenced in the page. To check this, open firebug, chrome dev tools or IE dev tools and check whether you have any errors
- A common error is to include the $(document).ready inside the view, and only reference jQuery at the bottom. This will generate an error because at that point `$` is not known. Possible solutions:

  1. Move the code to an external file and reference that file after the jQuery inclusion
  2. Move your jQuery declaration to the head-section (not recommended as it will slow down the page load)

Comment: no, its my fault when I copied to stack overflow, actually . is there.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console log? Are you including jQuery before the call to $(document).ready ?

Comment: I am not getting any error in console and I already included `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")`

Comment: Check the edit to my answer. If you're including the script inside the view, it's probably executed before jQuery is loaded. You either need to move it after jQuery or move jQuery to the head so it's loaded before your script

Comment: Could you post the result HTML (relevant parts) so I can have a closer look at what's going on?

Comment: This is the generated code of @Html.DropDownList- `<select name="PropertyContent" id="PropertyContent"><option value="442071">MBS</option> <option value="44050">MM</option> </select>`

Comment: The class-attribute is not there. You could use the id-selector instead. I've edited my answer

Comment: jqueryval will most likely only be adding the jquery validation scripts, not the jquery scripts. Check in your BundlesConfig which bundle you need to add for jQUery. I think it is most likely `~/bundles/jqueyr`

Comment: Should be `~bundles/jquery`.

Comment: Kenneth, JavaScript files are supposed to be loaded at the end of the page.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.test').change(function () {
        alert("1");            
    });
});
```

`$('.test').change(function () {` // on this part u need to add `'.'` in test

u forgot that it is a class.

Comment: I have updated my question. actually I tried with `$('.test')`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use following code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".test").live("change",function () {
        alert("1");            
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[Working FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/z8rH2/)**</kbd>

```
$(function () {
    $('#PropertyContent').change(function () {
        alert("1");
    });
});
```

Comment: Would you write the **generated** code for your `@Html.DropDownList`?

Comment: The `@Html.DropDownList` syntax will generate some `HTML` for you. I want that HTML to debug the problem.

Comment: This is the generated code of @Html.DropDownList- `<select name="PropertyContent" id="PropertyContent"><option value="442071">MBS</option>
<option value="44050">MM</option>
</select>`

Comment: So you haven't `class` for it at all. Use the `id` instead. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line somewhere in the view or the layout:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

Also your selector is not correct. You have no HTML element with `class="test"`.

Try `$('#PropertyContent')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to get the dropDownList by its Id like the code below.
I got a working example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/pzzQu/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#PropertyContent').change(function(){
        alert('1');
    });
});
```